# php inline style to my contact send form

Tags: php, html, forms, styles, inline

Here is what I got thus far. Where would I an my inline code? I also have the html page where the form is coded yet I have it linked to this php page. The form works great just wanted to add some style to it for a client.

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $subject_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
   } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
}
}

if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
  $phone_error = "Phone is required";
 } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
     // check if phone number is well-formed
     if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}     [\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
       $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
     }
   }

  if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
     $subject_error = "Subject is required";
   } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
     // check if subject is proper text form
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$subject)) {
       $subject_error = "Invalid URL"; 
     }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $message = "";
  } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }

   if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and      $subject_error == '' ){
       $message_body = '';
       unset($_POST['submit']);
       foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
           $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
       }
       // sends message to an email address specified. 
       $to = 'email@gmail.com';
       $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $name, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';
       }
   }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Start here => https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS and https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web - There's no better way than to learn.

Answer (score 0):

First, i think you have an error in your mail() function call.
The right way to send an email using this function is:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The $headers parameter is optional, but if you need to send stylesh emails, you'll need this.

An example of these headers:

```
$headers = "From: $name<$email>".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "X-Mailer:PHP/".phpversion()."".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8".PHP_EOL;
```

With these headers you are saying to the email client that you are sending html content, then, in your $message you can put some tags like:

```
$message = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name<br /><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong><br /><hr />Lorem ipsum";
```

Note: if you want to include some images, just use the  tag, but using publics urls in the src, like this:

```
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/emails/email-header.jpg" />
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Where exatly would I place the <img src Tag at?

Comment: You can place one or more <img> tags in your email content, the $message var. You place the <img> where you need. Maybe as header or footer, or maybe inline with some text. Its depends of your desired design.